# iAd turns white when switching view controller

Tags: ios, ios8, iad

I have an app that uses a UITabBar. Each one of the tabs displays an iAd at the bottom of its view.

When I go to a tab for the first time, the iAd displays great. When I switch back to a tab that's already loaded though, the iAd displays correctly for a second, and then turns white. It still shows iAd in the corner, and you can still click it, but the banner itself is gone.

I've simply embedded the iAds in my app using the iAd component in Interface Builder. What is going on here?

This happens on actual devices as well as the simulator. All are running iOS 8+.

**Edit:** I should mention that I hide the banner if it fails to receive an ad. This is a different issue.

Comment: I've had this problem for as long as I can remember. Still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the UI to drop the banner if it doesn't have any content loaded:

```
 #pragma mark - iAd support

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!bannerIsVisible)
    {
        // If banner isn't part of view hierarchy, add it
        if (adBanner.superview == nil)
        {
            [self.view addSubview:adBanner];
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");

    //Move the ad off screen
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

    adBanner.frame = CGRectOffset(adBanner.frame, 0, adBanner.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    //Hide it anyway
    bannerIsVisible = NO;

}
```

Also, you can go into the developer settings in the simulator or device and change the iAd fill rate to 100% to debug this.

Comment: I actually have already done that, and it works. The issue isn't that the banner isn't being filled, it's that it glitches and turns white even though it is filled.